# Как получить body от Post-запроса на java

Tags: java, servlet

Я получаю от php-сервера запрос на обработку данных, которые в формате json хранятся в body, как я могу достать именно эту json-строчку из request Post-запроса?

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос уже был дан на англоязычной версии сайта (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать следующий способ

```
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
        int intValueOfChar;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while ((intValueOfChar = reader.read()) != -1) {
            result.append((char) intValueOfChar);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
}
```